# replacing values in 0/1 filled matrix for it's corresponding columnnames when the row has more than one 1-value in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix like this one.

```
`      
      a b c d
 [1,] 1 0 0 0
 [2,] 1 0 0 0
 [3,] 1 0 0 0
 [4,] 1 0 0 0
 [5,] 1 0 0 0
 [6,] 1 0 0 0
 [7,] 1 0 0 0
 [8,] 1 1 0 0
 [9,] 1 1 0 0
[10,] 1 1 0 0
[11,] 0 1 0 1
[12,] 1 1 0 1
[13,] 1 1 0 1
[14,] 1 1 0 1
[15,] 0 1 0 1
[16,] 0 1 0 1
[17,] 0 1 0 1
[18,] 0 1 0 1
[19,] 0 1 1 0
[20,] 0 1 0 0
[21,] 1 1 1 1
[22,] 1 1 1 1
[23,] 1 0 1 1
[24,] 1 0 0 1
[25,] 1 0 0 1
[26,] 1 0 1 1
[27,] 1 0 1 0
[28,] 0 0 1 0
[29,] 0 0 1 0
[30,] 0 0 1 1`
```

code for reproducing:

```
`
mat1 <- as.matrix(cbind(c(rep(1,10),0,1,1,1,0,rep(0,5),rep(1,7),0,0,0),c(rep(0,7),rep(1,15),rep(0,8)),c(rep(0,18),1,0,1,1,1,0,0,rep(1,5)),c(rep(0,10),rep(1,6),1,1,0,0,rep(1,6),0,0,0,1)))


colnames(mat1) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
```

What I want is to check in each row if there are more then one values of 1. Like the first row for example row 8:

```
` 
     a b c d
[8,] 1 1 0 0`
```

Then I want to replace these 1 values for their corresponding column name.

Like this:

```
'
         a b c d
    [8,] a b 0 0`
'
```

I want to apply this to all 1 values in rows where there is more then one 1 value, while keeping the matrix structure.

Selecting the rows with more then one 1 value was not that hard, selecting the corresponding column names was also manageable, but then replacing them, I could not manage. 
This is what I have managed to do

```
`
apply(mat1,1, function(x) {
  #select rows with more then one 1
  if(sum(x) > 1) {
    #for every row with more than one 1; check if the value is 1
    for (i in 1:4) {
      if (x[i]==1) {
        #this seems to print every column name I need
        print(colnames(mat1)[i])
         #replacing should happen here I ques, but I can't get the location in the matrix.

      }
    }
    } 
  })
`
```

Would anyone be so kind to help me with this problem? Also, a better way than this double loop is welcome of course, but not necessary for my problem.

Comment: A matrix can't have entries of different classes. You have a numeric matrix right now, if you put letters in there **all** the values will be converted to  `character` class. Is this what you want?

Comment: Also, your shared data doesn't actually have `colnames`...

Comment: It is ok if all the letters become characters, I should have made that more clear. And you are right, I forgot to add the column names to the code. I did that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
col_n <- colnames(mat1)
res <- apply(mat1,1, function(x) {
  #select rows with more then one 1
  if(sum(x) > 1) {
    x[x == 1] <- col_n[x == 1]
  }
  return(x)
})

res <- t(res)
```

Comment: This is a simple way to do exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up code after Gregor's advice:

```
# create the dataframe
mat1 <- as.matrix(cbind(c(rep(1,10),0,1,1,1,0,rep(0,5),rep(1,7),0,0,0),c(rep(0,7),rep(1,15),rep(0,8)),c(rep(0,18),1,0,1,1,1,0,0,rep(1,5)),c(rep(0,10),rep(1,6),1,1,0,0,rep(1,6),0,0,0,1)))

# use only rows satisfying your condition
mat2 <- mat1[rowSums(mat1) > 1, ]
# set up char matrix
letterMat <- cbind(rep("a", nrow(mat2)), 
                   rep("b", nrow(mat2)), 
                   rep("c", nrow(mat2)), 
                   rep("d", nrow(mat2)))
# replace values in the char matrix
letterMat[mat2 == 0] <- 0
```

Comment: Don't use `apply(mat1, 1, sum)`, just use `rowSums(mat1)`.

Comment: This also looks like an interesting way to do it. But where do you create mat3?

Comment: Ah I see. That certainly deserves a point for creativity. Unfortunately I do not (yet) posses the privilege to hand you one.

Answer (score 0):

This is very loopy but gets the job done.

```
mat1 <- as.matrix(cbind(c(rep(1,10),0,1,1,1,0,rep(0,5),rep(1,7),0,0,0),c(rep(0,7),rep(1,15),rep(0,8)),c(rep(0,18),1,0,1,1,1,0,0,rep(1,5)),c(rep(0,10),rep(1,6),1,1,0,0,rep(1,6),0,0,0,1)))
colnames(mat1) <- c("a","b","c","d")
mat1sum <- rowSums(mat1)
for (i in 1:dim(mat1)[1]) {
 if (mat1sum[i] > 1) {
  for (j in 1:dim(mat1)[2]) {
   if (mat1[i,j]==1) {
      mat1[i,j] <- colnames(mat1)[j]
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Also an interesting way. Looks a little like python. Thanks for your answer!